# Encode multiple choice answer in R

Tags: r

I've a CSV dataset that looks like this:

```
Age;Functions;...
12;1,2,5;...
45;1,4,5,8;...
23;3;...
```

The first column is the age of the participant and the second column is a comma separated list of multiple choice answers of question 1. In this example, the first participant checks the 1st, 2nd and 5th checkbox and the 3rd participant checks only the 3rd checkbox.

Now, I want to evaluate the answers of question 1. The first step is to plot the number of answers of every possible answer. I've tried the following:

```
dataset$Functions <- strsplit(as.character(dataset$Functions), ",", fixed=T)
dataset$Functions <- lapply(dataset$Functions, factor, levels = 0:8, labels=c(
"no answer",
"checkbox 1",
"checkbox 2",
"checkbox 3",
"checkbox 4",
"checkbox 5",
"checkbox 6",
"checkbox 7",
"checkbox 8",
))
```

Additional I've tried to user mChoice:

```
library("Hmisc")
dataset$Functions <- lapply(dataset$Functions, mChoice, label="Functions")
```

But now, I don't know how to handle the list in the dataframe. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personaly I prefer to first transform the multiple choice variable into a series of dichotomous variables, one for each possible choice. For example, if you've got the following data frame :

```
d <- data.frame(age=c(25,35,45,55,65),var=c("1,2,3","1,2","3","2","1"))

  age   var
1  25 1,2,3
2  35   1,2
3  45     3
4  55     2
5  65     1
```

You can use the following code :

```
lev <- levels(factor(d$var))
lev <- unique(unlist(strsplit(lev, ",")))
mnames <- gsub(" ", "_", paste("var", lev, sep = "."))
result <- matrix(data = "0", nrow = length(d$var), ncol = length(lev))
char.var <- as.character(d$var)
for (i in 1:length(lev)) {
  result[grep(lev[i], char.var, fixed = TRUE), i] <- "1"
}
result <- data.frame(result, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
colnames(result) <- mnames
d <- cbind(d,result)
```

Which will give you three new variables :

```
  age   var var.1 var.2 var.3
1  25 1,2,3     1     1     1
2  35   1,2     1     1     0
3  45     3     0     0     1
4  55     2     0     1     0
5  65     1     1     0     0
```

From here, you can use each one of these new variables for statistics or cross-tabulation. If you want to generate a global table of the frequencies of the different choices, you can do this :

```
vars <- c("var.1","var.2","var.3")
as.table(sapply(d[,vars], function(v) {
  sel <- as.numeric(v==1)
  sum(sel)
}))
```

Which will give you :

```
var.1 var.2 var.3 
    3     3     2
```